# Controlling height in a container in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is something there is controlling the height on the div div tag with the green border here:

Can anybody see in the CSS what that is through the developer tools? I cannot figure it out.

I need to make a grid there is looking like this, but the height of the green bordered div tag has been stopping me. The important thing is that the text should still be centered.

This is actually how the code should be, but the height stops that:

Here is the code there is online:

```
div class="background-image" @Html.Raw(topImageStyling)></div>
       <div class="top-area" style="border: 4px solid red;">
            <div class="container col-md-8" style="border: 4px solid green;">


            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerText))
            {
                if (pageAlias == "Blog")
                {
                    <h1 class="header-xl center">
                        @Html.Raw(headerText)
                    </h1>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p class="header-xl center">
                        @Html.Raw(headerText)
                    </p>
                }
            }
            @if (CurrentPage.HasValue("imageTeaserText"))
            {
                <p class="sub-header center">
                    @Html.Raw(CurrentPage.imageTeaserText)
                </p>
            }


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is a `min-height:500px` setting the height to 500px. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just tried to delete the min height, but still nothing.

Comment: There are two `min-height`s. One in css/ebog/landingpage.css and one in bundles/css which looks like it is minified.

Comment: Thank you a lot again. Ah yes you are correct, The min-height you said, I tried to change to 50px, and it gets smaller. The problem is that it is the whole banner there is getting smaller, and not only the green border box. The bundles I just delete on localhost. I do not use that.

Comment: so you are saying the banner should stay the same size and only the text part should shrink?

Comment: Yes exactly. Do you have a suggestion? Maybe I should just skip the container, because there is all this styling on, and then text in div tag with my own class?

Comment: You could move the div with class "top-area" into the div with class "background-image." Then you would have to remove `position:absolute` from the background image div. This should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I just posted the code that there is online. The top-area should be inside the background.image, right? or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion in the coments, this is how the html should be structured. Then just remove `position:absolute;` from `.background-image` and remove `min-height:500px;` from `.container`

```
<div class="background-image" @Html.Raw(topImageStyling)>
    <div class="top-area" style="border: 4px solid red;">
        <div class="container col-md-8" style="border: 4px solid green;">

            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerText))
            {
                if (pageAlias == "Blog")
                {
                    <h1 class="header-xl center">
                        @Html.Raw(headerText)
                    </h1>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p class="header-xl center">
                        @Html.Raw(headerText)
                    </p>
                }
            }
            @if (CurrentPage.HasValue("imageTeaserText"))
            {
                <p class="sub-header center">
                    @Html.Raw(CurrentPage.imageTeaserText)
                </p>
            }


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MadsKristensen hmm I just tried the same thing I descibed in dev tools and it works. Are you sure you removed position:absolute everywhere?

Comment: @MadsKristensen oh you have two `background-image`s now. One inside another. Just remove one of them. And it still has position:absolute - that is why it is hidden.

Comment: Argh my bad, sorry. I just think it is weird. I deleted 100% the things now, but the banner is still gone. I uploaded the newest version again 1 minut ago

Comment: @MadsKristensen The html is fine now. Now you just have to make those css changes I told you about. Remove `min-height` from container and remove `position:absolute` from background-image.

Comment: @MadsKristensen The banner isn't showing because of the position:absolute. But once you remove that, you should see it again.

Comment: Thank you again a lot. There is no position:absolute in the container, but there was the min height i deleted. I also uploaded that one. Which line of code can you see the absolute?

Comment: It's in that bundles/css that I told you about before. And min-height is still in there too.

Comment: I found out why now. There was in my head:  @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js/modernizr") who did this. Everytime I save there is a grunfile minifing this, and it rules the SASS, so overriding all the time. It is here now, I say thank a lot. You helped me so much, thank you. I hope my head can manage to make the grid now :-/ I wish I was as fast as you, then I could make it until my deadline

Comment: @MadsKristensen glad I could help